# Is it possible to turn off ActionMailer emails when cucumber testing is happening on development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

Currently, my local development environment is setup to be able to send out actual emails. Because of this, deliveries are being made, and nothing is kept in the `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` table.  Is it possible to disable email sending in cucumber tests?  If so, what is the syntax to do this?  Or is there a better way to test emails being sent?

authentication_steps.rb:

```
Then /^I should receive a confirmation email$/ do
  email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  email.subject.should == "Welcome to our website!"
end
```

app/config/development.rb

```
  ...
  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true

  # Setup for local testing of emails using gmail test account
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
                                           :port => 587,
                                           :domain => ENV['MAIL_DOMAIN'],
                                           :authentication => 'plain',
                                           :enable_starttls_auto => true,
                                           :user_name => ENV['MAIL_USERNAME'],
                                           :password => ENV['MAIL_PASSWORD']
                                           }
  ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

or

just before tests

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test
```