# How to turn off ActionMailer in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer

I'm receiving real emails when I run my tests with RSpec. 
I've made everything as it was written in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961982/actionmailer-sending-real-emails-in-test-mode-how-to-turn-off/10970085#10970085) (I've add change my environment config to do not send emails, but it no make any effect at all. I'm thinking that my setting are replaced somewhere but I can't find where.

Here is my config for test env (**config/enviroments/test.rb**)

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
end
```

here are my **mailers**:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'hello@myapp.com'
  layout 'mailer'

  ADMIN_EMAIL = 'admin@myapp.com'
end

class AdminMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default to: "#{ADMIN_EMAIL}"

  def mandrill_client
    @mandrill_client ||= Mandrill::API.new MANDRILL_API_KEY
  end

  def new_user(user)
    #set required params
    mandrill_client.messages.send_template template_name, template_content, message
  end

end
```

It seems that I've missed something very obvious. However I need your help in breaking it up.

Comment: Check to see if you have a duplicate Action Mailer config somewhere, probably application.rb, and check if your tests are run in proper environment.

Comment: I've checked, no duplications, tests are running in a test environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `Mandrill::API` to send emails, and not `ActionMailer`, your settings to `ActionMailer` have absolutely no effect on it.

You should either find corresponding setting in the `Mandrill::API`, or stub the send method for tests.

I would actually suggest you to still use the `ActionMailer` with the Mandrill SMTP server:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port: 587,
  domain: Rails.application.config_for(:global)['domain'],
  authentication: 'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_apikey
}
```