# Rails 4 sending emails in the "Test" environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4, testing

Everytime I run tests, emails are actually sent. My `config/environments/test.rb` has this configuration

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

So I thought that whenever I run test, they should not be **really** sent, but when I run the command

```
RAILS_ENV="test" rake test
```

The emails get sent either way. For a moment I thought that maybe I was not using the right environment. But then I deleted completely `db/test.sqlite3` and immediately after I run the tests again. The file was again restored, which proves that I am actually running in the `test` environment.

What is going on? Why are my tests sending real mails? Could it have anything to do with the fact that I am using `deliver_now` on my app?

Comment: Do you have another `config.action_mailer.delivery_method` statement in your _environment.rb_ or in some of your initializers?

Comment: No, I do not have anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should at least be able to disable them by placing

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

in your *environments/test.rb* as suggested by [Brent Sullivan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4097181/brent-sullivan) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30825093/1744702).

Comment: Magic! Thanks! Still weird that :test did not work, but this does it :)

Answer (score 2):

Having the line `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp` in `config/environment.rb` overrides `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in `config/environments/test.rb`.

delete that line, `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp'` from `config/environment.rb` and place it in `config/environments/production.rb`. That allows you to place `ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :test` in `config/environments/test.rb` and the version you want in `config/environments/development.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Rails 6 but I thought it might help someone who is having this problem.

make sure to put the following in your config/environments/test.rb file:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test
```